# Annotation @AliasFor for derived property values

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-annotations

So I have a spring application with many DAOs that need to be pageable.
Every time I want to use a native query I need to wrap it into a separate count query eg.

```
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long>  {
    String QUERY = "select user_id,user_name from users";//a simplified example
    
    @Query(
        value = QUERY, 
        countQuery = "select count(1) from ("+QUERY+")"
        nativeQuery = true)
    Page<UserEntity> findUsers(Pageable pageable);
}
```

What I would like is to go away with repeatable parts eg.

```
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long>  {
    @PageableNativeQuery(value = "select user_id,user_name from users")
    Page<UserEntity> findUsers(Pageable pageable);
}
```

So I made an new annotation using @AliasFor:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@QueryAnnotation
@Documented
@Query(
    nativeQuery = true, //this works
    countQuery = "select count(1) from ("+value+")"//this does not work
    )
public @interface PageableNativeQuery {
    @AliasFor(annotation = Query.class, attribute = "value") String value() default "";
}
```

I can't figure out how to wrap up the query value into the count query. Any ideas are appreciated.